# Old trane furnace won't stay lit

Tags: hvac, furnace

I have a very old trane blu080f924b2 furnace that won't stay lit. It has a spark ignitor, that clicks, and lights the gas but it burns for a few seconds and then shuts off and the ignitor starts clicking again trying to light but it nothing else happens. It will click for 10 mins, then the gas lights again and goes back out after a few seconds.  It just keeps doing this over and over.

Comment: Have you searched _here_ for any of the myriad "my furnace won't light" questions?

Comment: Yes,  I'm not finding anything that matches my unit

Comment: While the exact brand/model can be important for specific details, 99% of the trouble shooting tips are the same.

Comment: All the answers I'm seeing are for the porcelain base flame sensors but mine doesn't have one

Comment: Have you gone through the cycle troubleshooting in the manual? It should give you good pointers on what to look at based on the step it stops at.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the flame detector is not working. Typically this is a probe-shaped sensor screwed into the side of the firebox, with a couple wires leading to the controller. They get covered with soot and sometimes just fail. It should be relatively easy to find and replace, inexpensive, and within the realm of DIY if you are minimally handy. I've had to replace mine once on 27 year old furnace. The symptoms you describe sound like that thermal sensor is not sending an electrical signal to the controller that it is ok to keep the gas valve open because it has successfully ignited. This would be the first thing I would try because it's cheap and easy; you would at least rule it out as being the problem, prior to more troubleshooting.

[image]

Comment: Could just as easily be the pressure switch. Edit: never mind, this is an 80% furnace, no draft inducer.

Comment: I've looked around to see if I have a flame sensor, I'm not seeing one. From what I've read it just has the electric ignition rod next to the gas line.  I stuck a toothbrush down in there and cleaned it up a bit but it didn't help.

Comment: It has to have a flame sensor, to prevent the unit from filling your home with unlit gas in the event the ignitor fails to light the burner. It is a safety feature, without it your entire home could become a bomb. Very old units that used a standing pilot light even had them (thermocouple/thermopile).

Comment: 2nd the thermocouple

Comment: I have a mercury flame sensor. It's a white rodgers 3098-182. I took the flame sensor out and cleaned it off and that didn't help so I took the sensor apart and manually held the button down and it's still having the same problem, I also replaced the thermostat. Is there anything else I should be checking? I'm disabled and can't afford to have someone come out and look at it.